# Windbg script - automatically parse each frame of a stack

Tags: scripting, windbg

Hullo,

I am looking at a few stacks recently, and I'm *manually* finding a certain thing that I want to get the address of so that I can delve inside it with `??`.

For example:

```
00 00000005`9c88a558 00007ffa`bc2713ed ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xa
01 00000005`9c88a560 00007ffa`be477d51 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xed
02 00000005`9c88a840 00007ffa`be477773 kernel32!WerpLaunchAeDebug+0x23a1
03 00000005`9c88adb0 00007ffa`bc351c1f kernel32!WerpLaunchAeDebug+0x1dc3
04 00000005`9c88ade0 00007ffa`bedaf1b3 KERNELBASE!UnhandledExceptionFilter+0x23f
05 00000005`9c88aed0 00007ffa`bed91e26 ntdll!memset+0xaaf3
06 00000005`9c88af10 00007ffa`beda349d ntdll!_C_specific_handler+0x96
07 00000005`9c88af80 00007ffa`bed648d7 ntdll!_chkstk+0x9d
08 00000005`9c88afb0 00007ffa`beda262a ntdll!RtlRaiseException+0xf67
09 00000005`9c88b680 00007ffa`aafc1b52 ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher+0x3a
0a 00000005`9c88bd80 00007ffa`ab14e820 function1(class foo1 * bar1 = 0x00000000`0eee4e10)+0xd2 [c:\path\source1.cpp @ 783]
0b 00000005`9c88bdc0 00007ffa`ab11b854 function2(class foo2 * bar2 = 0x00000000`0f034010)+0x540 [c:\path\source2.cpp @ 23044]
0c 00000005`9c88d420 00007ffa`ab06151c function3(class foo3 * bar3 = 0x00000005`9c88dd50)+0x584 [c:\path\source3.cpp @ 5671]
0d 00000005`9c88dcf0 00007ffa`aae1ef08 function4(class foo3 * bar3 = 0x00000000`80001a55)+0x3bc [c:\path\source4.cpp @ 218]
0e 00000005`9c88e7c0 00007ffa`aae2956b function5(unsigned short fcode = 0x3032, class foo3 * bar3 = 0x00007ffa`ab08e8de)+0x1fb8 [path\source5.cpp @ 108]
0f 00000005`9c88fab0 00007ffa`bed254f4 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x22
10 00000005`9c88fae0 00000000`00000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x34
```

I'm interested in extracting the 3 addresses of `0x000000059c88dd50`, `0x0000000080001a55` and `0x00007ffaab08e8de` and passing them **automatically** to a bunch of `?? ((foo3*) 0x000000059c88dd50)->WhatIAmInterestedIn` etc. commands so that I can quickly scan the output for results of interest.

Is there a way to script this parsing so I can trawl the stack of the current thread for any instances of `bar3`, grab that address and use it in `n` x `??` commands, just echoing whatever it finds to the Command Window, even if it's a memory access error, it could speed things up for me.

I was thinking about `!for_each_frame` but I must admit, I don't even know how to interrogate a specific frame for the presence or absence of a `bar3` and address, inside Windbg, *except* by doing it with my own eyes!

Comment: I've done something similar before by chaining [`!for_each_local`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-for-each-local) onto [`!for_each_frame`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-for-each-frame). Maybe something like this would work: `~*e!for_each_frame !for_each_local .if (@#Local == "bar3") { ?? bar3 }`

Comment: Thanks! With `!for_each_local .if ($spat ("@#Local","bar3") == 1) { .echo "Yes" } .else { .echo "No" }` I was able to get a good "yes" or "no" per frame... I'd just like to get the address of each `bar3` now... making progress.

Comment: I don't, do I. I don't need the address. I can `?? bar3->WhatIAmInterestedIn` directly, can't I? Because I've set the context to that frame. I _never_ knew!!!

Comment: By doing `!for_each_frame !for_each_local .if ($spat ("@#Local","hUser") == 1) { ?? bar3->WhatIAmInterestedIn }` I get a load of noise from `!for_each_frame` - is there a way I can do it _quietly_? The MS help says - "If you include CommandString, the debugger displays the frame and its index before the command is executed for that frame." - but I'd like to stop it doing that if it was possible.

Comment: `.f+` is also noisy when changing from frame to frame.

Comment: Making these extension commands silent sounds tricky. You might have some luck with some creative calls to [`.outmask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-outmask--control-output-mask-). Perhaps you could set `.outmask 0`, then only set `.outmask /d` before printing the variable, and when the script is finished. I've never tried that, so it's just a wild guess.

Comment: Thanks. I guess, what I was trying to achieve was an automated way of finding a needle in a haystack; just displaying however many `?? bar3->WhatIAmInterestedIn` I find in the stack, and nothing else - clean. If changing frame spits out loads of other stuff, that I'm not really that interested in, and I'm just filling the Command Window with other _junk_ then am I making things better? ;-)

Comment: Regardless, I will tinker with `.outmask`.

Comment: That's a lot better with `.outmask- 1` preceding `!for_each_frame` and `.outmask /d` afterwards. Not all on one line, yet, but that's no big deal - the concept is definitely there to work with. Much appreciated.

Comment: Nope, I made a mistake - I can't do `outmask- 1` before and then reset it just after - I'm gonna need to enable normal output before each variable prints, I think. And maybe use `.outmask- 2` to suppress the errors I also expect when `WhatIAmInterestedIn` is not there.

Comment: Is it possible to use `.for` or something to iterate through the frames of a stack, starting at 00 and using `.f+` until it errors, or something? Then I could happily use just the `!for_each_local` in a nice tidy script.

Comment: Or simply get the frame count for a thread (if that's so simple, why don't I know that already)?

Answer (score 2):

Any recent version of the debugger has built-in capabilities to script against the target with JavaScript.  WinDbg Preview in the store has UI with limited Intellisense for this as well.  You can do something like this easily.  Take the following example:

```
"use strict";

function* returnAllParameters(localName)
{
    var stack = host.currentThread.Stack;
    for (var frame of stack.Frames)
    {
        // Catch any exceptions that might occur due to inability to find PDB
        try
        {
            var locals = frame.Parameters;
            var local = locals[localName];
            if (local !== undefined)
            {
                yield local;
            }
        }
        catch(ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

An example of the result of this:

```
0:000> dx @$scriptContents.returnAllParameters("pExceptionRecord")
@$scriptContents.returnAllParameters("pExceptionRecord")                 : [object Generator]
    [0x0]            : 0x8be2f0ed00 [Type: _EXCEPTION_RECORD *]
```

Comment: Is there any documentation how to use things like `host.currentThread.Stack` and what other APIs are available? I'd played around with the new scripting support in the WinDbg preview and the biggest stumbling block was the lack of documentation -- relying only on examples is just no fun.

Comment: You should be able to go to http://aka.ms/JsDbgExt and see some documentation.  The host.* APIs are described at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/native-objects-in-javascript-extensions.  You should get some level of Intellisense in WinDbg Preview's script window.  In addition, anything under host.namespace.Debugger.* can be explored in the debugger.  You can just "dx Debugger" and click around.  Anything there should look largely the same in JavaScript.  You can add "-v" to see all the methods and "-h" to see any available help text (e.g.: dx -v -h Debugger).

Answer (score 0):

if you have source then you can follow messmers script and check the Parameters and Locals
(without source and a private pdb Parameters and Locals will spit undefined error )

if you do not have source and would like to grope the string output 
you can use some thing like this

```
function test(argstr)
{
    var backtrace = host.namespace.Debugger.Utility.Control.ExecuteCommand("kb")
    var collection = []
    var i = 0
    for (var frame of backtrace ) 
    {
        if( frame.toString().includes(argstr) ) {
        host.diagnostics.debugLog("found " + argstr + " at " + frame + "\n" )
        collection[i++] = frame.toString().split(" ")
        }
    }
    return collection
}
```

here is a stack and an output of text parsing

```
0:003> dx @$scriptContents.test("Rtl")

found Rtl at 03 02cdfe8c 76df37be 76e2f1d3 00000000 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
found Rtl at 04 02cdfea4 00000000 76e2f1d3 00000000 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
@$scriptContents.test("Rtl")                 : 

    length           : 0x2
    [0x0]            : 03,
    [0x1]            : 04,
clicking the dml 0x0 
you get the first collection and so on as below

0:003> dx -r1 @$scriptContents.test("Rtl")[0]
found Rtl at 03 02cdfe8c 76df37be 76e2f1d3 00000000 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
found Rtl at 04 02cdfea4 00000000 76e2f1d3 00000000 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
@$scriptContents.test("Rtl")[0]                 : 03,02cdfe8c,76df37be,76e2f1d3,00000000,00000000,ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
    length           : 0x7
    [0x0]            : 03
    [0x1]            : 02cdfe8c
    [0x2]            : 76df37be
    [0x3]            : 76e2f1d3
    [0x4]            : 00000000
    [0x5]            : 00000000
    [0x6]            : ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
0:003> dx -r1 @$scriptContents.test("Rtl")[1]
found Rtl at 03 02cdfe8c 76df37be 76e2f1d3 00000000 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
found Rtl at 04 02cdfea4 00000000 76e2f1d3 00000000 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
@$scriptContents.test("Rtl")[1]                 : 04,02cdfea4,00000000,76e2f1d3,00000000,00000000,ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
    length           : 0x7
    [0x0]            : 04
    [0x1]            : 02cdfea4
    [0x2]            : 00000000
    [0x3]            : 76e2f1d3
    [0x4]            : 00000000
    [0x5]            : 00000000
    [0x6]            : ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
0:003> kb
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
00 02cdfe10 76e2f20f 747e8f74 00000000 00000000 ntdll!DbgBreakPoint
01 02cdfe40 752ced6c 00000000 02cdfe8c 76df37eb ntdll!DbgUiRemoteBreakin+0x3c
02 02cdfe4c 76df37eb 00000000 747e8fb8 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
03 02cdfe8c 76df37be 76e2f1d3 00000000 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
04 02cdfea4 00000000 76e2f1d3 00000000 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
```